# Is there a "Rails Way" to fold a Twitter Bootstrap theme into a Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I purchased a nice-looking Twitter Bootstrap them online that is going to spice up my Rails 3.2.8 application. The package contains the following directories:

```
/css
/img
/js
```

Of course these files will have relative links to each other in them. Is there a standard way of integrating this type of stuff into the asset pipeline, or is it still a standard practice to put it under public?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to use the asset pipeline. Everything is moving that direction and it's really not any harder (except when it is). Your files will go in the `/app/assets/` directory.

For the css, you should be able to drop it right into `app/assets/stylesheets/`, just be sure that bootstrap is included first. There are several gems that make it easy to include bootstrap's files. I use [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass), but you might also try [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) (depends on if you want sass support or not). With either one, look at the readmes that I linked to as they include some useful details you'll want to know for each gem.

For the javascript, it should be about the same thing. In your application.js file, be sure that bootstrap is include **before** `//= require_tree .` in case the theme adds any custom javascript. Both of the gems I listed before also include the javascript files for bootstrap. You can read their documentation to see the details (it's almost exactly the same as normal for both gems).

As far as images are concerned, put them in the `app/assets/images/` directory and you'll have to change the stylesheets a bit for it to work. When an image is declared in the stylesheet, like `background: url('./images/bg.jpg');`, you'll need to use the `image_path` helper instead, so it would look like `background: url(image_path('bg.jpg'));`. Notice I just included the name of the image. The asset pipeline will automatically parse this to the correct path for you.

If the theme includes any custom fonts, you'll do the same as images except using the `asset_path` helper like so in your @font-face declaration:

```
url(asset-path('museo700.ttf', font));
```

There are also type-specific helpers you can use, such as `font-path`, `image-path`, etc. Either `asset-path` with a type declared or the type-specific helper will work, just be consistent with which one you use so as not to produce confusion.

You can place custom fonts in a directory something like `app/assets/fonts/`. The asset pipeline will automatically find them, since they're in the assets directory.

Comment: I am trying to use a theme from boostrap. But I am totally stuck, don't have any clue to proceed and make the theme work with my rails app. I have posted a question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650627/how-to-integrate-a-twitter-bootstrap-theme-into-an-rails-application 
could you please help me with my problem. I really need help :(