# How to integrate a Wrap Bootstrap theme into an Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have bought a twitter bootstrap theme from [wrapbootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/).
I already have a functional rails application. Now, I want to design my application by integrating the bootstrap theme into my application. 
I am new to this and I have no idea how to do it. After doing a lot of research on this, I found only a very few discussion regarding this issue. As for example I found this post: [Implementing WrapBootstrap theme into Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175879/implementing-wrapbootstrap-theme-into-rails-app)

But, I am not totally sure how the assets from the theme will be applied to my application. I have copied all the assets under my project's `app/assets/images`, `app/assets/javascripts` and `app/assets/stylesheets` folders from the theme's corresponding folders. Then, I got several error when I tried to run my app locally. I deleted my `application.css` file, after that it started working. But, I can not see any design from the theme being applied yet. What should I do to make this theme work into my rails app?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First check this screencast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

then I would add a bootstrap gem like bootstrap-sass, then add the JS files through the gem by adding them to the manifest, something like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

then i would get the css files that you bought from wrapboostrap and place them in you assets/stylesheets folder, then add the necesary markup and clases to your app this is how ive done it before.

hope it helps

EDIT:

Markup:

Check the template you downloaded, lets start with the navbar for example

Code from template:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="container">
                <a class="brand" href="index.html">Gaia Business</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="service.html">Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 5</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
    </div>
</header><!--/header-->
```

Now you need to place yourself in your app, if the navbar shows in every view on your app, you should mention it on the layouts/application.html.erb something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Golden Green Chlorella</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>

<%= render :partial => 'layouts/navbar' %>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

and last, do your navbar partial

_navbar.html.erb:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar glyph"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar glyph"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar glyph"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="container">
                <%= link_to "Your app", root_path, :class => "brand" %> 
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class=<%= current_page?(static_index_path) || current_page?(root_path) ? "active" : "" %> > <%= link_to (t "navbar.home"), root_path%></li>
                        <li class=<%= current_page?(static_know_path) ? "active" : "" %>> <%= link_to (t "navbar.know"), static_know_path%></li>  
                        <li class=<%= current_page?(static_buy_path) ? "active" : "" %>> <%= link_to (t "navbar.buy"), static_buy_path%></li>                       
                        <li class=<%= current_page?(static_faq_path) ? "active" : "" %>> <%= link_to "FAQ", static_faq_path%></li>           
                        <li class=<%= current_page?(static_contact_path) ? "active" : "" %>> <%= link_to (t "navbar.contact"), static_contact_path%></li>

                        <!-- <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> -->
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><%= link_to "English", static_english_path%></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Español", static_spanish_path%></li>
                    </ul> 
                </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
    </div>
</header><!--/header-->
```

That was only for the navbar, now you need to do the rest, add the markup your template shows you to do, with all your app, its not an easy job, but thats how its done.

Comment: I have done all the things except for your last line : " then add the necesary markup and clases to your app" could you please elaborate it a bit ?

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Just to be sure, do I need to do this after copying all assets from the theme to my app/asset ?

Comment: yeah when you coppy the assets from the template and change the markup you should see the efects

Answer (score 7):

make sure that while installing twitter bootstrap you should add following gem into your Gemfile under "group :assets"

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

then run bundle command.

Now, the theme "file_name.css" (file_name could be any) that u have downloaded just add it into "stylesheets" folder under app->assests->stylesheets

then open your application.css file in same folder there you will see

```
*= require_tree.
```

replace this line with

```
*= require "file_name.css"
```

NOTE: Don't forget to re-compile your assets or simply delete the content of your tmp/cache folder.

save it and reboot your server. it will apply your new theme.