# Rails with downloaded bootstrap theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

Sorry for this question, maybe its not the right question to be asked but I didn't find any help yet , I have downloaded a bootstrap theme called [BootClean](http://previews.sunflowertheme.com/bootclean_1.1/index.html) , then I browsed its file and found that it have a folder fonts under assets , when I googled for that I found it belongs to font awesome , and also I found how to use it with rails in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome) , but now:

**1- what about the other css and js files ?**

should I move them into assets/javascripts and assets/stylesheets and make them as required in my application

**2- what about the sub-folders which under the img and css folder ?**

**3- when I opened `index.html` I found this code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({
                submitSuccess: function ($form, event) { 
                    return true;
                }           
            });             
        }); 
    </script>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','../../www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-40162427-1', 'sunflowertheme.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

**how to deal in rails with the previous code which I found it inside html page ?**

this is the files and folders/sub-folders under bootclean

```
➜  bootclean  tree
.
├── 404.html
├── about-us.html
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap-responsive.min.css
│   │   ├── colors
│   │   │   ├── corporate-blue.css
│   │   │   ├── darkcyan.css
│   │   │   ├── dark-slate-gray.css
│   │   │   ├── default.css
│   │   │   ├── dodger-blue.css
│   │   │   ├── golden-rod.css
│   │   │   ├── green.css
│   │   │   ├── hot-pink.css
│   │   │   ├── indian-red.css
│   │   │   ├── medium-violet-red.css
│   │   │   ├── muted-teal.css
│   │   │   ├── orange.css
│   │   │   ├── sea-green.css
│   │   │   ├── soft-green.css
│   │   │   └── yellow.css
│   │   ├── flexslider.css
│   │   ├── flexslider.setting.css
│   │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│   │   ├── icons.css
│   │   ├── iview.css
│   │   ├── iview.setting.css
│   │   ├── jquery.fancybox.css
│   │   ├── sequence-slider.css
│   │   ├── sequence-slider.responsive.css
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   ├── style.responsive.css
│   │   └── styleswitch.css
│   ├── font
│   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot@
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   │   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── 404-name.png
│   │   ├── 50p.png
│   │   ├── about-us
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── introduce.png
│   │   │   ├── more-infomation-word.png
│   │   │   ├── team-1.jpg
│   │   │   ├── team-2.jpg
│   │   │   ├── team-3.jpg
│   │   │   ├── team-4.jpg
│   │   │   ├── team-5.jpg
│   │   │   ├── team-6.jpg
│   │   │   ├── team-7.jpg
│   │   │   └── team-8.jpg
│   │   ├── bg_direction_nav.png
│   │   ├── blog
│   │   │   ├── almond-blossom-5378_940.jpg
│   │   │   ├── dandelion-108459_940.jpg
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── last-post-1.jpg
│   │   │   ├── last-post-2.jpg
│   │   │   ├── last-post-3.jpg
│   │   │   └── red-arrows-108307_940.jpg
│   │   ├── clients
│   │   │   ├── aztec.png
│   │   │   ├── cisco.png
│   │   │   ├── cocacola.png
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── everyday.png
│   │   │   ├── gamescast.png
│   │   │   ├── hp.png
│   │   │   ├── igneus.png
│   │   │   ├── natural.png
│   │   │   ├── shell.png
│   │   │   ├── spinworkx.png
│   │   │   ├── vadafone.png
│   │   │   └── walmart.png
│   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   ├── dot.png
│   │   ├── fancy-plugin
│   │   │   ├── blank.gif
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── fancybox_buttons.png
│   │   │   ├── fancybox_loading.gif
│   │   │   ├── fancybox_overlay.png
│   │   │   └── fancy-new-sprite.png
│   │   ├── feature-bg.png
│   │   ├── feature-bottom-bg.png
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings.png
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
│   │   ├── index-body-readmore-bg.png
│   │   ├── index-footer-line.png
│   │   ├── iview_bg_direction_nav.png
│   │   ├── loader.gif
│   │   ├── logo-img.png
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   ├── menu-bg.png
│   │   ├── newsletter-bg.png
│   │   ├── next_arrow.png
│   │   ├── open-quote.png
│   │   ├── open-quote-white.png
│   │   ├── overlay-icon.png
│   │   ├── patterns
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── pattern10.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern11.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern12.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern13.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern14.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern15.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern1.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern2.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern3.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern4.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern5.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern6.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern7.png
│   │   │   ├── pattern8.png
│   │   │   └── pattern9.png
│   │   ├── portfolios
│   │   │   ├── almond-blossom-5378_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── ancient-21808_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── azalea-108516_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── balance-15712_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── clock-77497.jpg
│   │   │   ├── clock-77497_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── dandelion-108459.jpg
│   │   │   ├── dandelion-108459_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── dragon-rising-108423_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── drenthe-65488_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── euro-108238_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── flower-108134_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── piano-108436.jpg
│   │   │   ├── piano-108436_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   ├── red-arrows-108307_thumb.jpg
│   │   │   └── tanning-ara-108133_thumb.jpg
│   │   ├── prev_arrow.png
│   │   ├── pricingtable-lineOption.html
│   │   ├── sec-next.png
│   │   ├── sec-prev.png
│   │   ├── services
│   │   │   ├── abstract-21613.jpg
│   │   │   ├── ancient-21808.jpg
│   │   │   ├── business-15498.jpg
│   │   │   ├── catamaran-70954.jpg
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── dress-shop-97261.jpg
│   │   │   ├── glass-22032.jpg
│   │   │   └── russia-95311.jpg
│   │   ├── slides
│   │   │   ├── bg_6.jpg
│   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   ├── flex
│   │   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   │   ├── devices-mockup.png
│   │   │   │   ├── html5andcss3.png
│   │   │   │   └── ipadblack-mockup.png
│   │   │   ├── iview
│   │   │   │   ├── bg_1.jpg
│   │   │   │   ├── bg_2.jpg
│   │   │   │   ├── bg_3.jpg
│   │   │   │   ├── bg_4.jpg
│   │   │   │   ├── chrome.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │   │   ├── firefox.png
│   │   │   │   ├── html5andcss3.png
│   │   │   │   ├── ie.png
│   │   │   │   ├── imac.png
│   │   │   │   ├── ipad.png
│   │   │   │   ├── iphone.png
│   │   │   │   ├── macbook.png
│   │   │   │   ├── opera.png
│   │   │   │   └── safari.png
│   │   │   └── sequence
│   │   │       ├── Descr.WD3
│   │   │       ├── devices-mockup.png
│   │   │       ├── html5andcss3.png
│   │   │       ├── slide1.png
│   │   │       └── slide3.png
│   │   ├── social-spirit-mini.png
│   │   └── team
│   │       ├── cowboy-67630_640.jpg
│   │       ├── Descr.WD3
│   │       ├── girl-102829_640.jpg
│   │       ├── man-66942_640.jpg
│   │       ├── man-67467_640.jpg
│   │       ├── man-81361_640.jpg
│   │       ├── person-80115_640.jpg
│   │       ├── person-93459_640.jpg
│   │       └── teacher-99741_640.jpg
│   └── js
│       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│       ├── custom-fancybox-combined.js
│       ├── function.js
│       ├── iview.js
│       ├── jqBootstrapValidation.js
│       ├── jquery-1.8.2.min.js
│       ├── jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js
│       ├── jquery.easing.1.3.js
│       ├── jquery.flexslider.js
│       ├── jquery.gmap.min.js
│       ├── jquery.masonry.min.js
│       ├── jquery.placeholder.min.js
│       ├── jquery.quicksand.js
│       ├── raphael-min.js
│       ├── sequence.jquery-min.js
│       └── styleswitch.js
├── blog-item-left-sidebar.html
├── blog-item-right-sidebar.html
├── blog-left-sidebar.html
├── blog-right-sidebar.html
├── buttons.html
├── coming-soon.html
├── components.html
├── contact-style2.html
├── contact-us.html
├── faq.html
├── grid-layout.html
├── icons.html
├── index1.html
├── index-2.html
├── index2.html
├── index3.html
├── index4.html
├── index5.html
├── index6.html
├── index-flex-slider.html
├── index.html
├── index-iview-slider.html
├── login.html
├── pattern10.html
├── pattern11.html
├── pattern12.html
├── pattern13.html
├── pattern14.html
├── pattern15.html
├── pattern1.html
├── pattern2.html
├── pattern3.html
├── pattern4.html
├── pattern5.png
├── pattern6.html
├── pattern7.html
├── pattern8.html
├── pattern9.html
├── portfolio-2cols.html
├── portfolio-3cols.html
├── portfolio-detail.html
├── portfolio.html
├── pricing-tables.html
├── services.html
├── sign-in.html
├── sign-up.html
├── team.html
├── testimonials2.html
├── testimonials.html
└── typography-elements.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer i gave a few months ago:

[How to integrate a Wrap Bootstrap theme into an Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650627/how-to-integrate-a-twitter-bootstrap-theme-into-an-rails-application/15651241#15651241)

its the same principle in this

Comment: thanks for answer but what about the script code that inside html page ? and the sub-folders.

Comment: you can add them to the view that they are required, for instance if you need a script to run in the index you can add that script to the index.html.erb, or if you need to run the script in your whole app you can add it to the layouts application.html.erb