# Integrate bootstrap theme in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I would like to integrate a bootstrap theme from [WrapBootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/) in my Ruby on Rails website. What is the best approach to do it? Is there any `gem` I can use for it? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650627/how-to-integrate-a-twitter-bootstrap-theme-into-an-rails-application

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Awesome man!