# how do I use a bootstrapious theme on Ruby on Rails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried looking through already asked questions like basic bootstrap  [Integrate bootstrap theme in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142870/integrate-bootstrap-theme-in-ruby-on-rails) 
and [How to integrate a Wrap Bootstrap theme into an Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650627/how-to-integrate-a-wrap-bootstrap-theme-into-an-rails-application)

but when I try just adding the folders from the free downloaded bootstrapious theme, I get the basic over lay of the site, but nothing is functioning.

None of the scroll activated animations, such as when you scroll down you see an image sitting with text kind of through it, But the image is suppose to load after you get to that section and it isn't a sqaure picture its a rounded/ circle image that moves from right to left and will stay there once you have scrolled past that part of the site.

Am I missing some part of the view set up, or is it going to be in the controller, or even a special spot in the js/stylesheets that didn't get linked in?

The theme i'm trying to use is https://bootstrapious.com/p/it-worker-portfolio-theme

You can see a live preview at http://it-worker.ondrejsvestka.cz/

I have asked this question on that site itself but have yet to get reply, any help is appreciated.(trying to make my first active site for personal website) once I can get this working i'd like to tweak and refine but just cant even get it to work as is.