# Import Twitter Bootstrap Template to Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, import

I'm currently involved in a complex project which I will require help from this forum in order to complete! I am a novice; and have thus far only completed Michael Hartls Tutorial.

Currently I am attempting to import this template into my new application. I have successfully got Bootstrap working; as the generic text improves. This shows that it is working!

However, when I paste the content from the Index file it does not display correctly. I imagine this is due to incorrect placing of CSS and JS files in the ruby folder.

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

Thanks!

Comment: What is that link for?

Comment: Hey. That is the template I'm attempting to get imported in my Ruby Application! Thanks.

Comment: You need to do more than paste a file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650627/how-to-integrate-a-wrap-bootstrap-theme-into-an-rails-application

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot! Fingers crossed!